# Suitability on MO of question on teaching engineers mathematical thinking skills

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

Recently, I asked a question on MSE about [teaching engineers mathematical thinking skills](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634690/teaching-engineers-mathematical-thinking-skills). Would this question be suitable for MO, where it might reach more professionals involved in teaching mathematics to engineers?

I fully recognize that the question might be deemed too subjective for MO. Certainly, it is not directly about research level mathematics.

Please also let me know should you feel that the question is unsuitable now, but could be made appropriate with some rewriting, be it minor or extensive.

**Edit:** I have decided not to post the question on MO at this stage (if at all). However, if you would like to provide an answer then please go to the MSE link above or leave a "comment" at [The Mathematics Teaching Community](https://mathematicsteachingcommunity.math.uga.edu/index.php/918/mathematical-thinking-skills-for-engineers) where I have just posted a submission. I suspect that the latter community might be more appropriate than MO for my question. Thank you to everyone who provided input on Meta whether my question was suitable.

Comment: Vote here if you want to express: yes, this is **on-topic.**

Comment: Vote here if you want to express: no, this is **off-topic.**

Comment: How long should I wait before the voting for on or off-topic is considered concluded? At the time of writing this comment, the scores are equal. That said, there are enough votes for off-topic that my proposed question might very well be closed, were I to post it. Please note that I wish to abide by the norms of the MO community.

Comment: Basically I think it could make sense to wait until somebody actually gives an answer here. I merely added the voting comments, since recently there was some discussion something like this should be done to avoid many downvotes on the question itself. We do not have many precedents regarding this procedure. IMO the question is borderline. It is hard to predict what would happen when you post it.

Comment: Whats the worst that will happen if you post it. Closed question ? Big deal.

Comment: @quid: Thanks for the explanation. I'll certainly wait a bit longer before deciding whether to post.

Comment: @Piyush Grover: Quite right, of course. However, I would like to see if anyone has suggestions for improving my question. Moreover, if it's clearly inappropriate for MO then I'd rather not post at all and just leave the original question up on MSE.

Comment: @Piyush Grover: I'd just like to add that I would rather, if possible, post an appropriate and well-formulated question and receive quality answers than rush to post a poorer-quality question and have it swiftly closed. With hindsight, perhaps I posted too quickly on MSE, but I am trying to learn from the feedback I am getting there.

Comment: A question about teaching mathematicians engineering skills (or what engineering point of view has to offer mathematics) would be also quite interesting.

Comment: @Gil Kalai: Interesting thought. My background is originally in mathematics, but I suspect some engineering has rubbed off on me the past several years. Some of my colleagues who started off in mathematics have considerably more engineering experience.

Comment: @Gil Kalai: (comment continued) I think I'll ask them what they think re your suggested questions. I'll also ponder the matter myself.

Comment: @Gil Kailai: Perhaps [this article](http://www.intuac.com/userport/john/writing/nthinking.html) sheds some light on how engineers think.

Answer (score 6):

I think your question is a case of doubt. -- If it is asked by a well-known
mathematician or by an established MO user and if it is formulated well,
I think chances are high that it will make its way onto the network-wide
[hot questions list](http://stackexchange.com/questions) and receive many good answers and many upvotes.
Though on the other hand, if it is asked by an MO "novice" under a pseudonym,
and if it is not formulated so well and maybe also contains typo's or grammar
mistakes, then I guess it will likely be downvoted and closed.

Comment: I think I understand your point, although I would hope that a question, doubtful or otherwise, would be judged largely on its own merits (or lack thereof) and not so much on who asked it. That said, I can appreciate that one's area(s) of expertise and standing within a community do weigh in as factors.

Comment: @JW: As far as I can tell, questions which have a definite answer are actually
"judged largely on their own merits". -- But regarding soft questions,
there is the perceived risk that if they are welcomed too much, more and
more of them will be asked, and they will eventually dominate the site
and the level will decrease. Mathematicians usually do like occasional
good soft questions, but not too many.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifying comment. Assuming my question is either already a good soft question, or (more likely) can be improved so that it becomes one, how do I know whether it isn't a soft question too many for MO? I suppose the answer is to ask on Meta, which is what I have done. So far, the impression I have is that while some people are fine with the question, just as many are not.

Comment: (My assumption in the comment above could be false, of course.)

Answer (score -1):

What *would* perhaps be on-topic:

> What are published research papers that discuss the teaching of mathematical thinking skills to engineers?

But (since MO is not an opinion or a discussion forum) what would *not* be on-topic:

> What techniques have you used that were effective in teaching mathematical thinking skills to engineers?

As we know, not everything that is interesting and important is on-topic in MO.

Comment: To the downvoters: do you disagree with the first being on-topic, or with the latter being off-topic, or with both, or with still something else?

Comment: I'm also curious about the precise reasons for the downvotes. I do appreciate Gerald Edgar's providing advice that could lead to a better question.

Comment: I downvoted this answer for the second question. Questions about mathematical pedagogy are definitely on-topic on Math Overflow, so it is misleading and incorrect to suggest that the second question would not be appropriate.

Comment: I think the second question is also on topic. In any case I upvoted since I think the answer is useful.